# How to pad contents in XAML user control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have an XAML user control that has a Grid with various TextBoxes and Labels in it.

```
<UserControl>
  <Grid Background="#FFE8EEF7" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <!-- just various TextBoxes and Labels here -->
    <TextBox x:Name="txtBottomTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="800,37,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" IsEnabled="False"/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I then have the user control on my main window like so:

```
<Window>
  <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <MyCtrlLib:GenParams Name="genParams1" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Everything is fine except for the lack of space between the bottom-most TextBox and the bottom of the user control. There is perhaps three pixels of space at most between the two, and so I would like to have more padding (maybe up around 8 pixels). However, I've tried dumping in padding where I can, but nothing works like I want it to.

Any suggestions on how I can force some padding between the bottom-most TextBox and bottom of the user control?

Comment: Can't you just set its margin, like `Margin="800,37,0,8"` ?

Comment: @McGarnagle - Thanks! That did the trick. I'm a newb when it comes to WPF, so I miss the seemingly most obvious things. I'd tried monkeying around with the margins on everything but the actual TextBox itself. Add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as such. Thanks again.

Comment: No prob, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the TextBox margin like this (the values go clockwise starting from left):

```
Margin="800,37,0,8"
```